# Data Table Plugin with ajax call with parameter as string

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am using first time Data Table Plugin of jquery.

I want to pass string in Ajax Call using DataTable Plugin.

```
var attrObj = '{"location":"['+devices+']","stDate":"'+stDate+'","enDate":"'+enDate+'","days":"'+days+'","fileName":"'+fileName+'"'+
        ',"category":"'+category+'"}';


$(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "ajax": content.jsp,
                //what i need to write here to pass above attrObj string
            } );
        } );
```

attrObj String will be pass in content.jsp.
in this file json parser will parse this string into json object 
and after then that will send to server.
server will give respose in string. 
From this result i want to make table using data Table.

Please give me direction how to done this.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, i send json data (attrObj  in your sample) via post request.
You must override **fnServerData**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "content.jsp",
        "data": attrObj,
        "success": fnCallback
      } );
    }
  } );
} );
```

You can find more information here http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks

Comment: oColumn is undefined in jquery.DataTables.js   and i am replace xhr.php with index.php where my code is written